# Deserialize string into values using format pattern

Tags: python, serialization, format

I'm trying to get a good solution for a (de-)serializer.
I've got a format pattern and all the values to put in.

The format pattern is as follows:

```
msg = '$bla,%d,%02d,%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d' % (kwargs['...'], ...)
```

When I serialize the values, I get the following string:

```
bla,1990,12,24 13:37:11.001
```

But I also have to deserialize it. The pattern can strongly vary in length and types.
I'd like to deserialize the string based only on the format pattern.

Any ideas how this is achievable?

EDIT: I'm using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with regex, with some assumptions. Here's a partial example, you'd probably need to add to it for a full solution. Basically, we convert each print format, to a regex that matches it, by pieces.

```
import re
formattuple = (1990,12,24,13,37,11,1) 
formatstr = 'bla,%d,%02d,%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d'

def rep_format(fmt):
    fmt = fmt.group(0)
    if fmt[0] != '%':
        return fmt
    if fmt == '%d':
        return r'(\d+)'
    ftype = fmt[-1]
    if ftype == 'd':
       fwidth = int(fmt[1:-1])
       return r'(\d{%d})'%(fwidth)
    else:
       return fmt

scanstr = re.sub(r'%\d+[df]', rep_format, formatstr)
scanstr
'bla,(\\d+),(\\d{2}),(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}).(\\d{3})'

fstr = formatstr%formattuple
fstr
'bla,1990,12,24 13:37:11.001'

match = re.match(scanstr, fstr)
match.groups()
('1990',
 '12',
 '24',
 '13',
 '37',
 '11',
 '001')
mtuple = tuple(int(x) for x in match.groups())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can fully control the protocol, or saying `format after serialization`, I suggest using some existing solution, e.g [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) provided by Python standard library, [Json](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) which is very popular in web, or [Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which is cross-language provided by Google

[Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> formattuple = (1990,12,24,13,37,11,1) 
>>> s = pickle.dumps(formattuple)
>>> s
'(I1990\nI12\nI24\nI13\nI37\nI11\nI1\ntp0\n.'
>>> pickle.loads(s)
(1990, 12, 24, 13, 37, 11, 1)
```

[Json](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> formattuple = (1990,12,24,13,37,11,1)
>>> s = json.dumps(formattuple)
>>> s
'[1990, 12, 24, 13, 37, 11, 1]'
>>> json.loads(s)
[1990, 12, 24, 13, 37, 11, 1]
```

Be aware that json has some limitation, such as a bit more difficult to serialize and de-serialize objects other than dict, list and tuple. And would NOT de-serialize to a totally identical format, because some data structure such as tuple is not existed in json

[Protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is a more powerful but more complex solution. You need to define the data schema first.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the protocol. The incoming string always looks similar to the one I posted.